# How can I get a String with from dateTime field in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I´m trying to get a SubString from datetime field. I get this field from a dataset like this:

```
fecha_nacimiento = row[7].ToString().Substring(1,9);
```

the compiler doesn´t say any error but when I execute i Get the following error:

> start index can´t be longer that length of string.

I repeat that the value of row[7].ToString  is 11/11/2010 0:00:00

Comment: Try printing out row[7].ToString() and see what you get

Comment: What are you trying to get exaclty? `DateTime.ToString()` provides better ways to format a date

Comment: obviously they 8th row has length 1 or less

Comment: Looks like there's nothing in that row at position 7.

Comment: it says that row[7] is empty.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? We're going to need more information to help you. We can tell you what this error means, but that's about it.

Comment: Have you checked the result of the ToString() method? It seems that the string is empty. Also remember that accessing a string with the Substring() method is done with a zero based index. So if you want to include the first character call Substring(0, 9).

Comment: row[7].ToString works well,  it has this string= 22/11/2010 0:00:00

Comment: @Mikelon85 Are you doing this in a loop then maybe for one of the rows the `ToString()` results in an empty string

Comment: My thoughts exactly, V4Vendetta! Mikelon, do this ToString when you get the exception.

Comment: Ok thanks v4Vendetta . I´m doing a loop and i have some rows with empty field. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a breakpoint on that line and add a watch for this value:

```
row[7].ToString()
```

it would seem to me that it's empty.

This code would help catch this:

```
string date = row[7].ToString();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(date) && date.Length > 8)
{
    fecha_nacimiento = date.Substring(1,9);
}
```

As the comments have shown though, there are better ways to parse dates!

Answer (score 1):

First, that error means you've got a string that's either empty or one character long - it doesn't have a character at position 1 (remember, they start at index 0).

Second, if the data in that cell is a DateTime already, then use one of the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) methods to get the string (`ToString`, `ToShortDateString` or `ToLongDateString`) you need. Like this:

```
fecha_nacimiento = ((DateTime)row[7]).ToShortDateString();
```

**EDIT** Casting isn't necessary if you just want to use the `ToString` method.

Otherwise, first [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) it to a DateTime, then use one those methods.

Answer (score 1):

As you already proofed that the string contains "22/11/2010 0:00:00". Use

```
row[7].ToString("d") which will result in "22/11/2010"
```

here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.80).aspx

[Edit] Renan is correct of course when he states that this will only work if the objects contained in your data source are of type DateTime. See his answer above as well for more details.

Comment: That will work if the data in the cell is a DateTime. If it is a string that coincidentally has that text, it'll result in "22/11/2010 0:00:00" again.

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer accordingly. Because of the questions title, I was assuming that the objects indeed are of type DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the pattern in the method "tostring ()"

You can choose from many existing format. Watch the official documentation here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.80).aspx

Like this:

```
string fecha_nacimiento = string.Empty;

if(row[7] != null)
{
   if(row[7].toString() != string.Empty)
   {
       string fecha_nacimiento = row[7].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
       //OR
       string fecha_nacimiento = row[7].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
       // etc...
   }
}
```

Comment: You can but that will also fail when row[7] is Null or empty surely ?

Comment: Yes of course. But this is another problem. If you use the substring it's the same problem. You can check if the value is not empty before getting the date. i edit my answer

Comment: That will only work if it's know *at compile time* that `row[7]` is of type DateTime. `object` doesn't have a `.ToString()` overload with format parameter.

Comment: Yes I know. But as the author has mentioned it tries to convert from the format "DateTime"

Answer (score 0):

This means that `row[7].ToString()` has a length of 0.

Just to prove a point, if you do:

```
string test = string.Empty;

Console.WriteLine(test.Substring(1, 9));
```

It would give you the exact same error message.